# Delete Android app installation history

Tags: google-play-store

I last used Android about 7 years ago, yet Google is still storing a list of “installed” apps. How do I delete this?

I can browse it at https://play.google.com/apps.

Things I’ve tried that didn’t work:

- Ensuring Google doesn’t still think I have an Android device - they don’t
- Clicking on the app then clicking the “Installed” button - “no device” error
- Going to “Delete a Google service” - not listed
- Going to “Apps and services” - listed, but no option to delete
- Browsing Google Play settings - no option to delete data

I’m hoping for a solution better than deleting my entire Google account.